# Replace element of ArrayList if object of same value already present in it

Tags: java, arraylist, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for my chat app. I have an ArrayList which contains last message, username, time. Whenever a new message arrives in JSON format then it should check if JSON contained username is present in ArrayList or not. If present, then updates the ArrayList otherwise add in ArrayList.
Here is my code:-

```
private Emitter.Listener handle1 = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        ChatLists.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JSONObject data = (JSONObject)args[0];
                try {
                    String sendername = data.getString("sender");
                    String lastMessage = data.getString("message");
                    String profileImage = data.getString("Profile");
                    String token = data.getString("fb_token");
                    chat_list chat_list = new chat_list(sendername,
                            profileImage, lastMessage, "0", "", "dummy", token);


                    if (chat_lists.size()==0){
                        chat_lists.add(chat_list);
                    }else {
                        for (int i=0;i<chat_lists.size();i++){
                            if (chat_lists.get(i).getContactname().equals(sendername)){
                                chat_lists.set(i,chat_list);
                            }else {
                                chat_lists.add(chat_list)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    contactlistAdapter = new ContactlistAdapter(chat_lists);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactlistAdapter);
                    contactlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: so whats the problem your facing now ?

Comment: I'm getting 2 copies of the same item.

Comment: first copy didnt get replaced and second copy present at the last right ?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `contains()` & `set()` methods of ArrayList in a logical way to solve your problem like below:-

```
if(chat_lists.contains(username)) 
 chat_lists.set(indexOf(username), new_username);

else chat_lists.add(new_username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
if(chat_lists.contains(chat_list)){
  chat_lists.remove(chat_list);
  chat_lists.add(chat_list);
} else {
  chat_lists.add(chat_list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about architecture patterns, for example, MVP.
You need to store your messages somethere (in Model) and update view relative to data.

Also read about RecyclerView, cause of ListView is a little bit deprecated

Answer (score -1):

```
if (chat_lists.get(i).getContactname().equals(sendername)){
```

above statement has problem them. It's not getting under your if condition and following the `chat_lists.add(chat_list)` statement.

Instead `equals` use `ignoreCasequals`. If still wont it solve your problem please use debug mode or logs check `chat_lists.get(i).getContactname()` 
and `sendername` same or not.